# Why are immutable borrows ok after mutable borrows in closures?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

While reading Steve Donovan's article [Why Rust Closures are (Somewhat) Hard](https://stevedonovan.github.io/rustifications/2018/08/18/rust-closures-are-hard.html) I stumbled upon this code snippet:

```rust
let mut x = 1.0;
let mut change_x = || x = 2.0;
change_x();
println!("{}", x);
```

Steve claims that the code should not compile because of this error:

> previous borrow occurs due to use of `x` in closure

But when I run the code in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), the code works fine. It outputs "2".

I suppose that is because the closure `change_x` borrows the variable `x` mutably from the enclosing environment, but ...

1. Why does the immutable borrow in the `println!` macro work? `x` is mutably borrowed in the `change_x` closure defined above. Steve seems to suggest that this should be an error. Has the compiler been modified to handle this situation differently since the article was published?
2. The code doesn't compile when I remove the `mut` marker from `change_x`. Why?

Side note: the compiler version used by the Playground app is 1.48.0 at the time of posting this question.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: For context, non-lexical lifetimes came with Rust 2018 edition (version 1.31) and this article was probably written with version 1.28

Comment: Will do, @Shepmaster. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the tip.

Comment: And thanks @kmdreko, yeah Steve used Rust 1.28.0